# android maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

During my studies i must develop an application base on google maps, user should found QRcode on the map and scan them.

So i create an android application including ggogle play lib and including the sdk library. i suppose i have created the right api key in my account google console whith tha SHA1 of my computeur.

**class java**

```
package com.example.mapa;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    int i=0;
    GoogleMap map=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    }
   }
```

**class XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<permission
android:name="com.example.mapa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission       android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapa.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my api key"/>
</application>


</manifest>
```

can every one can tel me why i have button on my map button i have a white screen all the time, with fragments or whithout, it's the same with a map view.

Comment: Are you getting the solutions or not?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the while-loop is the problem? I don't see a change of `i` so this appears to be a infinite loop.

Try to get the reference to the `GoogleMap` in the `onResume()` method without a loop, like

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: yes i removed it, but i still have a white screen with my button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the this [Image](http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/7049/przechwytywaniempp.png).

At the moment, referencing the Google Android Map Api v2 you can't run google maps v2 on Android emulator; you must use a device for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you didn't update the "my api key" value with your api key on purpose.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my api key"/>
```

And I don't remember seeing this in the docs, maybe you should remove it:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

Also COARSE_LOCATION is misspelled:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION" />
```

And you declared this twice. hehe. =)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```